# Exclude word from redirect location from folder in NGINX

Tags: nginx, server, location

I have a folder on site, that redirect all traffic to other server folder:

```
location /dir {
 alias /var/www/html/directory/public;
 ...
}
```

But I also have routes like this: site.com/dirname , site.com/dirl etc. I want to redirect all traffic that matches /dir/(.*) to that location, but when I use exact **/dir/** in location or ^~ /dir/, the route get **file not found** error.

How to simultaneously use this location for folder and urls starting form dir? Thank in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `~ /dir(*.)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‍‍‍Try:

```
location ~ /dir(.*) {
 alias /var/www/html/directory/public;
 ...
}
```